# Tableview java display next row database

Tags: java, mysql, tableview, javafx-8

I have some issues trying to figure why the value being overwritten to the same table row's and column's from the Tableview once another RFID tag is being detected from the reader.

All I wanted is to make sure that every data are able to display the next available row which it seems like I couldn't solve the matter. I hope you guys can help. Thanks

Here is my declaration of the tables

```
public class tableview extends Application implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<UserDetails> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserDetails, String> epc;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserDetails, String> modCode;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserDetails, String> modClass;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserDetails, String> modName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserDetails, String> timestamp;




    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        epc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("epcNo"));
        modCode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("moduleCode"));
        modClass.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("moduleClass"));
        modName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("moduleName"));
        timestamp.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("timestamp"));

public synchronized void moduleInfo(String epcString) {
        try {
            conn = db.getConnection();
            int i = 0;
            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement()
                    .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM module_info_table where rfid_tag_id = " + epcString);

            while (rs.next()) {
                String modulecode = rs.getString("module1_code");
                String moduleclass = rs.getString("module_class");
                String modulename = rs.getString("module1_name");
                String epc = rs.getString("rfid_tag_id");
                String timestamp = rs.getString("last_updated");

                System.out.println(modulecode);
                if (epcString.equals(epc)) {
                    data2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                    data2.add(new UserDetails(epc, modulecode, moduleclass, modulename, timestamp));
                }
            }
            table.setItems(data2);
            table.refresh();

            db.closeConn();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }

    }
public class PrintListener implements ReadListener {
    @Override
    public void tagRead(Reader r, TagReadData tr) {

        try {

            String epcString = tr.getTag().epcString();

            if (!map.containsKey(epcString)) {


                moduleInfo(epcString); < -- call to here


            }
            table.setItems(data);
            table.refresh();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

This is my tableview:

RFID TAG: 45

```
   EPC     Module Code   Module Class      Module Name         TimeStamp
   45      ET123       DCPE/FT/5D        Computer System     Mon Oct 4 01:13:23am
   -         -              -                  -                   -
   -         -              -                  -                   -
```

New RFID Tag: 100 (It will overwrite previous records)

```
   EPC     Module Code   Module Class      Module Name         TimeStamp
   100      ET468       DEEE/FT/8G       Computer Science     Mon Oct 4 01:13:23am
    -         -              -                  -                   -
    -         -              -                  -                   -
```

As you can see the images below:
The first RFID tag detected and it will display the content once it matches with the mysql database

After a new RFID tag is being detected, the latest RFID tag Overwrites the old records which I don't want it to happen.

Take note that the tableview has many columns and rows which is not shown property because I had to crop down which took alot of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    data2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        epc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("epcNo"));
        modCode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("moduleCode"));
        modClass.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("moduleClass"));
        modName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("moduleName"));
        timestamp.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("timestamp"));
```

I've tested placing the observablelist here and it worked! 
Now I know that data2 has to be declared before the while((rs.next)) Loop

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting data2 here:

```
data2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

remove it and put it here

```
public synchronized void moduleInfo(String epcString) {
    try {
        data2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        conn = db.getConnection();
        int i = 0;
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement()
                .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM module_info_table where rfid_tag_id = " + epcString);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String modulecode = rs.getString("module1_code");
            String moduleclass = rs.getString("module_class");
            String modulename = rs.getString("module1_name");
            String epc = rs.getString("rfid_tag_id");
            String timestamp = rs.getString("last_updated");

            System.out.println(modulecode);
            if (epcString.equals(epc)) {

                data2.add(new UserDetails(epc, modulecode, moduleclass, modulename, timestamp));
            }
        }
        table.setItems(data2);
        table.refresh();

        db.closeConn();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);

    }
```

now it should be fixxed if im not blind :P

Comment: It still gave me the same results\